# Google Drive integration error php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have to add file in Drive. I have tried following code but give an error.

**Purpose :**

I have to use an api to add file to google drive.

**Code**

```
    <?php
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Content-Type: application/pdf', // todo: runtime detection?
                'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]' 
        ),
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents ( '/path/to/file.pdf' ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1 
) );
try {
    if (false === ($resp = curl_exec ( $ch ))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl error ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ": " . curl_error ( $ch ) );
    }
    $parsed = json_decode ( $resp, true );
    if (! $parsed || $parsed ['code'] !== 200) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'google api error: ' . $resp );
    }
} finally{
    curl_close ( $ch );
}
var_dump($resp);
```

**Error  :**

> Notice: Undefined index: code in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/uploadtodrive/index.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: google api error: { "error": {
>   "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message":
>   "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location":
>   "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }
>   in /opt/lampp/htdocs/uploadtodrive/index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/uploadtodrive/index.php on line 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have create a webapplication and client ID ,Secrete as well as redirect URL. redirect URL is missing.

```
<?php

$GAPIS = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
$GAPIS_AUTH = $GAPIS . 'auth/';
$GOAUTH = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/';

$CLIENT_ID = '709846732498-t19mhuuvq0nqtxxxxim8.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$CLIENT_SECRET = 'K8YxRshxxxx-5Sh3jKa';
$REDIRECT_URI = 'http' . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? '' : 's') . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$SCOPES = array($GAPIS_AUTH . 'drive', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'drive.file', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'userinfo.email', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'userinfo.profile');
$STORE_PATH = 'credentials.json';

function uploadFile($credentials, $filename, $targetPath)
{

    global $GAPIS;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GAPIS . 'upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($filename));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array('Content-Type : text/plain', 'Content-Length:' . filesize($filename),
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken($credentials))
    );

    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($postResult, true);
}

function getStoredCredentials($path)
{

    $credentials = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);

    if (isset($credentials['refresh_token']))
        return $credentials;

    $expire_date = new DateTime();
    $expire_date->setTimestamp($credentials['created']);
    $expire_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $credentials['expires_in'] . 'S'));

    $current_time = new DateTime();

    if ($current_time->getTimestamp() >= $expire_date->getTimestamp())
    {
        $credentials = null;
        unlink($path);
    }

    return $credentials;
}

function storeCredentials($path, $credentials)
{

    $credentials['created'] = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    file_put_contents($path, json_encode($credentials));
    return $credentials;
}

function requestAuthCode()
{

    global $GOAUTH, $CLIENT_ID, $REDIRECT_URI, $SCOPES;
    $url = sprintf($GOAUTH . 'auth?scope=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&client_id=%s&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline',
            urlencode(implode(' ', $SCOPES)), urlencode($REDIRECT_URI), urlencode($CLIENT_ID)
    );
    header('Location:' . $url);
}

function requestAccessToken($access_code)
{

    global $GOAUTH, $CLIENT_ID, $CLIENT_SECRET, $REDIRECT_URI;
    $url = $GOAUTH . 'token';
    $post_fields = 'code=' . $access_code . '&client_id=' . urlencode($CLIENT_ID) . '&client_secret=' . urlencode($CLIENT_SECRET)
            . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($REDIRECT_URI) . '&grant_type=authorization_code';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

function getAccessToken($credentials)
{

    $expire_date = new DateTime();
    $expire_date->setTimestamp($credentials['created']);
    $expire_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $credentials['expires_in'] . 'S'));

    $current_time = new DateTime();

    if ($current_time->getTimestamp() >= $expire_date->getTimestamp())
        return $credentials['refresh_token'];
    else
        return $credentials['access_token'];

}

function authenticate()
{

    global $STORE_PATH;

    if (file_exists($STORE_PATH))
        $credentials = getStoredCredentials($STORE_PATH);
    else
        $credentials = null;

    if (!(isset($_GET['code']) || isset($credentials)))
        requestAuthCode();

    if (!isset($credentials))
        $credentials = requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);

    if (isset($credentials) && isset($credentials['access_token']) && !file_exists($STORE_PATH))
        $credentials = storeCredentials($STORE_PATH, $credentials);

    return $credentials;
}

$credentials = authenticate();

$result = uploadFile($credentials, 'my_file.txt', 'vasim.txt');

if (!isset($result['id']))
    throw new Exception(print_r($result));
else
    echo 'File copied successfuly (file Id: ' . $result['id'] . ')';
```